# How can I save fineuploaders uuid in a database?

Tags: javascript, php, fine-uploader

I am using http://fineuploader.com that automatically generates uuid to the image names. I want to store the uploaded image uuid in a database. I have found out that it should be possible to get the uuid with php  `$uuid = $_REQUEST['qquuid'];`

I have tested to put it it in my php code but nothing is saved. Can I pass it from the javascript code to a php function with my mysql insert?

How do I get all the uuid from the uploaded images passed to a php function so I can save them to my database?

Fineuploader javascript coce

```
<script src="assets/fine-uploader.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
            request: {
                // REQUIRED: We are using a custom domain
                // for our S3 bucket, in this case.  You can
                // use any valid URL that points to your bucket.
                endpoint: "upload.fineuploader.com",

                // REQUIRED: The AWS public key for the client-side user
                // we provisioned.
                accessKey: "AKIAJB6BSMFWTAXC5M2Q"
            },

            template: "simple-previews-template",

            // REQUIRED: Path to our local server where requests
            // can be signed.
            signature: {
                endpoint: "/s3demo.php"
            },

            // OPTIONAL: An endopint for Fine Uploader to POST to
            // after the file has been successfully uploaded.
            // Server-side, we can declare this upload a failure
            // if something is wrong with the file.
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: "/s3demo.php?success"
            },

            // USUALLY REQUIRED: Blank file on the same domain
            // as this page, for IE9 and older support.
            iframeSupport: {
                localBlankPagePath: "/server/success.html"
            },

            // optional feature
            chunking: {
                enabled: true
            },

            // optional feature
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },

            // optional feature
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                method: "POST",
                endpoint: "/s3demo.php"
            },

            // optional feature
            validation: {
                itemLimit: 5,
                sizeLimit: 15000000
            },

            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    notAvailablePath: "assets/not_available-generic.png",
                    waitingPath: "assets/waiting-generic.png"
                }
            }
        })
            // Enable the "view" link in the UI that allows the file to be downloaded/viewed
            .on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {
                var $fileEl = $(this).fineUploaderS3("getItemByFileId", id),
                    $viewBtn = $fileEl.find(".view-btn");

                if (response.success) {
                    $viewBtn.show();
                    $viewBtn.attr("href", response.tempLink);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

php code I use to upload the files

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP Server-Side Example for Fine Uploader S3.
 * Maintained by Widen Enterprises.
 *
 *
 * This example:
 *  - handles non-CORS environment
 *  - handles size validation and no size validation
 *  - handles delete file requests for both DELETE and POST methods
 *  - Performs basic inspections on the policy documents and REST headers before signing them
 *  - Ensures again the file size does not exceed the max (after file is in S3)
 *  - signs policy documents (simple uploads) and REST requests
 *    (chunked/multipart uploads)
 *
 * Requirements:
 *  - PHP 5.3 or newer
 *  - Amazon PHP SDK (only if utilizing the AWS SDK for deleting files or otherwise examining them)
 *
 * If you need to install the AWS SDK, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/installation.html.
 */

// You can remove these two lines if you are not using Fine Uploader's
// delete file feature
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// These assume you have the associated AWS keys stored in
// the associated system environment variables
$clientPrivateKey = $_SERVER['AWS_SECRET_KEY'];
// These two keys are only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
// or if you are, for example, confirming the file size in a successEndpoint
// handler via S3's SDK, as we are doing in this example.
$serverPublicKey = $_SERVER['PARAM1'];
$serverPrivateKey = $_SERVER['PARAM2'];

// The following variables are used when validating the policy document
// sent by the uploader. 
$expectedBucketName = "upload.fineuploader.com";
// $expectedMaxSize is the value you set the sizeLimit property of the 
// validation option. We assume it is `null` here. If you are performing
// validation, then change this to match the integer value you specified
// otherwise your policy document will be invalid.
// http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/api/options.html#validation-option
$expectedMaxSize = null;

$method = getRequestMethod();

// This second conditional will only ever evaluate to true if
// the delete file feature is enabled
if ($method == "DELETE") {
    deleteObject();
}
// This is all you really need if not using the delete file feature
// and not working in a CORS environment
else if ($method == 'POST') {

    // Assumes the successEndpoint has a parameter of "success" associated with it,
    // to allow the server to differentiate between a successEndpoint request
    // and other POST requests (all requests are sent to the same endpoint in this example).
    // This condition is not needed if you don't require a callback on upload success.
    if (isset($_REQUEST["success"])) {
        verifyFileInS3();
    }
    else {
        signRequest();
    }
}

// This will retrieve the "intended" request method.  Normally, this is the
// actual method of the request.  Sometimes, though, the intended request method
// must be hidden in the parameters of the request.  For example, when attempting to
// send a DELETE request in a cross-origin environment in IE9 or older, it is not
// possible to send a DELETE request.  So, we send a POST with the intended method,
// DELETE, in a "_method" parameter.
function getRequestMethod() {

    if ($_POST['_method'] != null) {
        return $_POST['_method'];
    }

    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
}

function getS3Client() {
    global $serverPublicKey, $serverPrivateKey;

    return S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => $serverPublicKey,
        'secret' => $serverPrivateKey
    ));
}

// Only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
function deleteObject() {
    getS3Client()->deleteObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $_POST['bucket'],
        'Key' => $_POST['key']
    ));
}

function signRequest() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $responseBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $contentAsObject = json_decode($responseBody, true);
    $jsonContent = json_encode($contentAsObject);

    $headersStr = $contentAsObject["headers"];
    if ($headersStr) {
        signRestRequest($headersStr);
    }
    else {
        signPolicy($jsonContent);
    }
}

function signRestRequest($headersStr) {
    if (isValidRestRequest($headersStr)) {
        $response = array('signature' => sign($headersStr));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("invalid" => true));
    }
}

function isValidRestRequest($headersStr) {
    global $expectedBucketName;

    $pattern = "/\/$expectedBucketName\/.+$/";
    preg_match($pattern, $headersStr, $matches);

    return count($matches) > 0;
}

function signPolicy($policyStr) {
    $policyObj = json_decode($policyStr, true);

    if (isPolicyValid($policyObj)) {
        $encodedPolicy = base64_encode($policyStr);
        $response = array('policy' => $encodedPolicy, 'signature' => sign($encodedPolicy));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("invalid" => true));
    }
}

function isPolicyValid($policy) {
    global $expectedMaxSize, $expectedBucketName;

    $conditions = $policy["conditions"];
    $bucket = null;
    $parsedMaxSize = null;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($conditions); ++$i) {
        $condition = $conditions[$i];

        if (isset($condition["bucket"])) {
            $bucket = $condition["bucket"];
        }
        else if (isset($condition[0]) && $condition[0] == "content-length-range") {
            $parsedMaxSize = $condition[2];
        }
    }

    return $bucket == $expectedBucketName && $parsedMaxSize == (string)$expectedMaxSize;
}

function sign($stringToSign) {
    global $clientPrivateKey;

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac(
            'sha1',
            $stringToSign,
            $clientPrivateKey,
            true
        ));
}

// This is not needed if you don't require a callback on upload success.
function verifyFileInS3() {
    global $expectedMaxSize;

    $bucket = $_POST["bucket"];
    $key = $_POST["key"];

    // If utilizing CORS, we return a 200 response with the error message in the body
    // to ensure Fine Uploader can parse the error message in IE9 and IE8,
    // since XDomainRequest is used on those browsers for CORS requests.  XDomainRequest
    // does not allow access to the response body for non-success responses.
    if (getObjectSize($bucket, $key) > $expectedMaxSize) {
        // You can safely uncomment this next line if you are not depending on CORS
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        deleteObject();
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "File is too big!"));
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("tempLink" => getTempLink($bucket, $key)));
    }
}

// Provide a time-bombed public link to the file.
function getTempLink($bucket, $key) {
    $client = getS3Client();
    $url = "{$bucket}/{$key}";
    $request = $client->get($url);

    return $client->createPresignedUrl($request, '+15 minutes');
}

function getObjectSize($bucket, $key) {
    $objInfo = getS3Client()->headObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $key
        ));
    return $objInfo['ContentLength'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine Uploader's S3 uploader sends [an upload success POST request to your server](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html#optional-server-side-tasks-all-browsers) after the file has been successfully sent to S3.  A number of parameters are sent in the payload of this request, which is URL encoded.  The name of the uuid parameter for the S3 upload success request is "uuid".  So, you can parse it server-side, in your upload success POST handler, with `$_POST['uuid']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass it from JavaScript to PHP, you could probably just pass it through $.get and have it process the info on a PHP script.

```
$.get("YourScript.php?uuid="+ UUIDvariable);
```

That will pass the variable in your JavaScript, which contains the UUID, to your PHP script. Then from your PHP script, just use $_GET to grab the variable value, and then use that value to insert it into your MySQL database.

```
if(isset($_GET['uuid']))
{
  $uuid = $_GET['uuid'];
 //Your code to insert to database
}
```